# SQL Database not storing user inputs

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've created a registration form which takes a user's name, username, email and password. I've also created a sql database using XAMPP control panel, named the database 'registration' and created a table called 'users' to store all the inputs.

When the user enters this data, they should be presented with the login page and in the background the data should be store int he database..but when I opened up phpmyadmin to check the table, there is no data saved.

Below is the code I used to sent the inputs from the user to the database which is my 'server.php' file:

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$name = "";
$email = "";
$username = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'registration');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']); 
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($name)) { array_push($errors, "Name is required");  
  }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
  }
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password) 
              VALUES('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
}

// ... 
// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: https://georginahughes48.wixsite.com/makeupyourmind');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Please let me know if any further code is needed to assist me with this issue..Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if your query execution failing or throwing any error?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy sorry I don't understand you..I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: did you checked this file is connected to database or not

Comment: Turn on error reporting in PHP,  and test your INSERT query to see if it is executing or returning an error. At the very lease, echo the query and see if it executes in phpAdmin (or similar)

Comment: What is the response status? Are the system redirecting you to login page?

Comment: Also, by adding a unique key to the users table on username and email, and using the ```INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE``` syntax, you can eliminate the "check query".

Comment: @AkshayParate how would I check this please?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy how do I do this please?

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan yes, it just redirects me to the login page straight away.

Comment: if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL;
  } add this code

Comment: @SloanThrasher you've lost me, I'm completely new to this so I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I should add : if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL; } to my server.php file yes?

Comment: if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
die();
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
die();
}

add this. and tell me the response

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan I've tried your suggestion..but still the users table is empty in the database when I check phpmyadmin

Comment: I am trying to debug. That's why I put a die there. What message are you getting?

Comment: You shouldn't escape the passwords before you hash them either. That changes the password. There's no need anyway since you're only saving the hash. Actually, you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with placeholders instead of concatenating your queries. Then you don't need to care about escaping the values at all.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable! To avoid this use prepared statements and dont use md5 use password_hash()  something like this password_hash($input['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 17)

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan okay, where exactly do you want me to put this line of code please? So I can tell you the response.

Comment: @user9435526 replace  $password = md5($password); with $password=password_hash($input['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 17).  and make sure your db password can hold at least 80 chars.  This encrypted hash operates off blowfish and is long.

Comment: @Jonny Okay I will do that..but would you know why the user input is not being stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After connection code add this line

```
if($db->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Error: ( " .$db->errorno. " )". $db->error;
    die;
}
```

Just replace this code

```
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password) 
              VALUES('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
    if( mysqli_query($db, $query))
    {
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
       header('location: login.php');
   }
   else
   {
      echo mysqli_error($db);
   }
  }
}
```

Check if it gives any errors.

Comment: when I replace my code with yours, it just refreshes the registration page and does not direct me too the login page..does that indicate that my database is not connected? and so, how do I fix this please?!

Comment: Like the function `mysqli_connect_error()` says, it's for _connection_ errors, not query errors. You should use `mysqli_error($db)` to get the query error: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: it indicates query execution is failed.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy okay, how do I fix this query execution failure please?

Comment: when you go to the phpmyadmin page, what password are you giving? Or there is no password?

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan there is no password used when I'm accessing phpmyadmin page, although when I first used mysqlworkbench I set up the password to be 'root'

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I have adapted your changes..the only difference I get is the registration page is refreshed instead of being presented with the login page.

Comment: @user9435526 execute changes. i think database connection is failing

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy 'Data too long for column 'password' at row 1' is now the error message I am getting when enter 'hey123' for a new user registration

Comment: change the data type for password column to either text or if you have chosen varchar increase it 300

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy it worked! Thank you so so so so so so so much! Really appreciated it!

Comment: in future if you hash or encrypt make sure datatype or varchar length is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code in try catch block. Replace your register part with this:

```
    // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
    try {
      if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password) 
                  VALUES('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: login.php');
      }
   } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
```

This will give you error if anything breaks in between, else your code is seems okay.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..although it still does the same thing, presents me with the login page after the 'Sign up' button is pressed and when I check the user table in phpmyadmin there is no data present :(

Comment: @user9435526 add die(); after exception message for tracing if any exception is throwing or not

Comment: The issue has been resolved now, but thanks for your time and effort! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : change the code like following:

```
        <?php
        session_start();

        // initializing variables
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
        $username = "";
        $errors = array(); 

        // connect to the database
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

        if (!$db) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // REGISTER USER
        if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
          // receive all input values from the form
          $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']); 
          $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
          $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
          $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
          $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

          // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
          // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
          if (empty($name)) { array_push($errors, "Name is required");  
          }
          if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
          }
          if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
          if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
          if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
            array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
          }

          // first check the database to make sure 
          // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
          $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
          $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
          $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

          if ($user) { // if user exists
            if ($user['username'] === $username) {
              array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
            }

            if ($user['email'] === $email) {
              array_push($errors, "email already exists");
            }
          }

          // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
          if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

            $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password) 
                      VALUES('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
                if( mysqli_query($db, $query))
                {
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                   $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                   header('location: login.php');
               }
               else
               {
                  echo mysqli_error($db);
               }
          }
        }

        // ... 
        // ... 

        // LOGIN USER
        if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
          $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
          $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

          if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
          }
          if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
          }

          if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
              $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
              $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
              header('location: https://georginahughes48.wixsite.com/makeupyourmind');
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
          }
        }

        ?>
```

Assuming there is no password for mysql.

Step 2:
Recheck mysql connection and table names case and spelling

Step 3:
Check the nullable fields, field types and length in table. If you have primary key check if auto increment is there or not. hope this will help.

Comment: There is a password for mysql, if I change my code to replicate yours I just get an error message in regards to the missing password.